# IDEA: Adding default serial version ID for Serializable howto?

Tags: serialization, syntax, intellij-idea

Using `IntelliJ`, whenever I add `implements Serializable` it does not offer to add a default serial version id, similar to how Eclipse does it.

[image]

Using `Eclipse`, if i do the same, i get a warning and an offer to

[image]

**How can i get the same behaviour in IntelliJ please?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This inspection is disabled by default, you need to enable it in Settings:

[image: enable inspection]

Once enabled, the quick fix becomes available on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while standing on the highlighted class name:

[image: Alt+Enter]

Comment: Thank you sir. Helpful as always